How to force DuckDB to reconnect to a file and prevent it from remembering contents of a deleted database file?
Motivation
I'm working on a larger dashboard application which uses duckdb. I found out a bug which in a nutshell is like this:
# create new connection
con = duckdb.connect('/somedir/duckdb.db')

# do something

# remove or replace the file
Path('/somedir/duckdb.db').unlink()
shutil.copy('/otherdir/duckdb.db', '/somedir/duckdb.db')

# create new connection to the *new* file with same location
con = duckdb.connect('/somedir/duckdb.db')

# PROBLEM: the connection remembers the contents from the first file!

Question
How do you guarantee that when you create a new duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection object or an Exception is raised with:
import duckdb

con = duckdb.connect('/somedir/duckdb.db')

that duckdb would not try to use some internal cache? In essence, I want a new, clean connection to the specified location or an Exception to be raised no matter what has happened before in the application.
MWE for reproducing the problem
from pathlib import Path
import duckdb

filepath = Path("/tmp/test_duckdb/data.db")
filepath.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

con = duckdb.connect(str(filepath))
con.sql(f"CREATE TABLE first AS SELECT 42 AS i, 84 AS j")
print("before removing:\n" + str(con.sql("show tables")))

filepath.unlink()

con2 = duckdb.connect(str(filepath))
print("after removing:\n" + str(con2.sql("show tables")))
con2.sql(f"CREATE TABLE first AS SELECT 42 AS i, 84 AS j")

Actual outcome:
before removing:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ first   │
└─────────┘

after removing:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ first   │
└─────────┘

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CatalogException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 15
     13 con2 = duckdb.connect(str(filepath))
     14 print("after removing:\n" + str(con2.sql("show tables")))
---> 15 con2.sql(f"CREATE TABLE first AS SELECT 42 AS i, 84 AS j")

CatalogException: Catalog Error: Table with name "first" already exists!


Desired outcome:
Raise an Exception on the second connect attempt as there are open connections to the file.
Note:
The problem is part of a larger application and fixing the bugs there is not the point of this question. The point is that even if you have a bug in your application logic, how do you prevent duckdb giving connection to already deleted/replaced database file? Is there some duckdb.clear_all_caches() method or duckdb.connect(filepath, raise_if_open_connections=True)?
Edit: Should probably explicitly add that I'm aware that connections should be closed. The question is: Can you do something about it if the connections are not closed?

Edited the desired outcome: Raise an Exception if there's already a connection to the file which and the file contents have changed.

Based on https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html#persistent-storage, you should use con.close() or the context manager form with duckdb.connect() as con: to ensure the persistent connection gets closed.
This can't be reproed with
from pathlib import Path
import duckdb

filepath = Path("./data.db")

with duckdb.connect(str(filepath)) as con:
    con.sql(f"CREATE TABLE first AS SELECT 42 AS i, 84 AS j")
    print("before removing:\n" + str(con.sql("show tables")))

filepath.unlink()

with duckdb.connect(str(filepath)) as con2:
    print("after removing:\n" + str(con2.sql("show tables")))
    con2.sql(f"CREATE TABLE first AS SELECT 42 AS i, 84 AS j")

duckdb.connect() seems to internally use the "instance cache" for which there seems to be no iteration or clear methods, so I don't think there is a way to easily ensure this.

Thanks. That is correct. I'm trying to find a way to prevent this from happening in an application which has not closed all of it's connections. Note the part "even if you have a bug in your application logic, how do you prevent duckdb giving connection to already deleted/replaced database file`". Ideally this most likely should just raise an Exception.

See my edit – but the issue is of course that unlink() doesn't actually delete the file as long as there's a file handle open to it, so it's not deleted at all before the handle is closed...

Wow I didn't think about unlink() not deleting the file. Thanks (and +1) for your efforts!

Okay I think I got some sort of solution figured out. The idea is to use a get_connection function which acts as a wrapper for duckdb.connect, and:

Renames the file temporarily to some.db.temporary (or any other name)
Creates a new connection to some.db and check with describe that it is really empty. If not, raises RuntimeError.
Renames the file back to some.db
Returns a connection to some.db

Of course, you might not need to rename if you're just making a new connection, so apply the logic as you wish. Below is a solution which tries to be sufficient answer for this question.
MWE and example output

This MWE demonstrates that the function works (1) when app has no bugs and db file is deleted and/or replaced (2) when app has unclosed connection(s) and the db file is removed and (3) when app has unclosed connection(s) and the db file is replaced.

import shutil
from pathlib import Path

import duckdb


def get_connection(filepath: Path):

    if filepath.exists():
        tmp_file = filepath.with_suffix(".db.temporary")
        filepath.rename(tmp_file)
    else:
        tmp_file = None

    # Safety guard.
    with duckdb.connect(str(filepath)) as con:
        if not con.sql("describe;").df().empty:
            err = RuntimeError(
                "The duckdb file is not empty. This is most likely due to a connection "
                f"to the {filepath} which has not been closed properly before calling "
                "this function."
            )
        else:
            err = None

    if tmp_file:
        tmp_file.rename(filepath)

    if err:
        raise err

    return duckdb.connect(str(filepath))


# Setup
filepath = Path("/tmp/test_duckdb/data.db")
filepath_cache = Path("/tmp/test_duckdb/cache.db")
filepath.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
filepath.unlink(missing_ok=True)
filepath_cache.unlink(missing_ok=True)

# Create a cached table to another file. This will replace the file.
with duckdb.connect(str(filepath_cache)) as con:
    con.sql("CREATE TABLE cached AS SELECT 5 AS x")


# Create first table
con = duckdb.connect(str(filepath))
con.sql("CREATE TABLE first AS SELECT 0 AS x")
print("before removing:\n" + str(con.sql("show tables")))
con.close()


# Case 1: Duckdb file is removed
filepath.unlink()

con_case1 = get_connection(filepath)
con_case1.sql("CREATE TABLE case1 AS SELECT 1 as x")
print("con_case1:\n" + str(con_case1.sql("show tables")))
con_case1.close()

# Case 2: Duckdb file is replaced
filepath.unlink()
shutil.copy(filepath_cache, filepath)
con_case2 = get_connection(filepath)
con_case2.sql("CREATE TABLE case2 AS SELECT 2 as x")
print("con_case2:\n" + str(con_case2.sql("show tables")))


The solution uses the get_connection which works as described above.

(1) when app has no bugs and db file is deleted and/or replaced

In this case, all connections are closed properly, like in the MWE: con.close() and con_case1.close().
Output (this is what you'd expect):

before removing:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ first   │
└─────────┘

con_case1:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ case1   │
└─────────┘

con_case2:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ cached  │
│ case2   │
└─────────┘


(2) when app has unclosed connection(s) and the db file is removed

Now, comment out the con.close() to create a bug. In this case, the get_connection function protects you from creating a new connection (as it shows the old file contents!) and raises a RuntimeError:

before removing:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ first   │
└─────────┘

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 52
     46 # con.close()
     47 
     48 
     49 # Case 1: Duckdb file is removed
     50 filepath.unlink()
---> 52 con_case1 = get_connection(filepath)
     53 con_case1.sql("CREATE TABLE case1 AS SELECT 1 as x")
     54 print("con_case1:\n" + str(con_case1.sql("show tables")))

...

RuntimeError: The duckdb file is not empty. This is most likely due to a connection to the /tmp/test_duckdb/data.db which has not been closed properly before calling this function


You can check yourself that con_case1 = duckdb.connect((str(filepath))) would return the original db which would cause pretty interesting bugs in an application. Here the outcome would be (Note: we were modifying the original table, and have the first leaked here):

con_case1:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ case1   │
│ first   │
└─────────┘

(3) when app has unclosed connection(s) and the db file is replaced

Now, comment out the code for case 1 (and leave con.close() commented out) to create a bug just before the file is replaced.
Again, the get_connection function safeguards you from making a connection to the old file contents.

Output:
before removing:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ first   │
└─────────┘

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 60
     58 filepath.unlink()
     59 shutil.copy(filepath_cache, filepath)
---> 60 con_case2 = get_connection(filepath)
     61 con_case2.sql("CREATE TABLE case2 AS SELECT 2 as x")
     62 print("con_case2:\n" + str(con_case2.sql("show tables")))

...

RuntimeError: The duckdb file is not empty. This is most likely due to a connection to the /tmp/test_duckdb/data.db which has not been closed properly before calling this function.


You can check yourself that con_case2 = duckdb.connect(str(filepath)) would again return the original db which would cause bugs in an application. Here the outcome would be:

con_case2:
┌─────────┐
│  name   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ case2   │
│ first   │
└─────────┘


The RuntimeError might have a better error text for the case where there's data in the table. But you get the idea :)

Also adding threading.locks to handle multithreaded case and handling of other than Path inputs is left out for simplicity.
